# return value from a string in list python

Tags: python

I have `test = ['1234']` and I need to return only `'1'`

How should I get it?

I have been trying `s.find('1')` but this gets me the index of `1`, its not that I want.

I can use `print( "First character in string : " , string[0] )` but again it works with an index.

I tried this:

```
test = ['1234']
test[0][0]
```

but it works only if I know that `1` is first element of my string. What should I do if I didn't know this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you don't know where the `'1'` is, then you *have* to find the index. What is wrong with `return '1'`? Perhaps you could update the question with some more examples of what `test` might look like and what you need to return in each case.

Comment: Indeed, if you know you need to return `1`, why do you need to examine `test` at all? I think you are oversimplifying the description of the task; what property of `test` leads you to believe  or know that `1` is the correct return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the index of your string and find the element stored at that index. However, it doesn't make sense to me as you already have the element you want to find. I am assuming you have posted your true purpose.

Try this:

```
li = ['12345']
def foo():
    return li[0][li[0].find('1')]

print("Answer:", foo())
```

Outputs:

```
Answer: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '12345'
def foo():
    return s[0]
foo()
```

Comment: i'm asking i need to return `1` not just first element, this fucntion is just personal

Comment: to be honest I didn't understand you